# Area of square inscribed in a cubic inequality.

Tags: geometry

[image]

The question, a square having sides parallel to the coordinate axes is inscribed by the in the region $y \le -x^3 + 3x$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive. If area can be written as $A^{1/3}  + B^{1/3}$ where $A$ and $B$ are integers then find $a$ and $b$.

Please ignore the questions below, I only need help for finding area.

My take to the problem, I roughly drew the curve using wavy curve method and then took two points on $x$ axis $a$ and $b$ as the sides of square, now I found the other points by using the curve I was given which will be $3a - a^3$ and $3b - b^3$ .

[image]
After that I used the property of square of equal sides but I am unable to solve them for area. I know that area can be found if I know the value of $ab$ (area = $(b-a)^2$) but how can to manipulate these equations to find $ab$.

Comment: Hi Akshat, welcome to MSE! Questions that are images cannot be searched. Please type out the question instead of referring to a picture.

Comment: Can i edit it now or would i have to upload it again?

Comment: There is an edit button at the bottom of the original post.  Also, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4208079/edit) is the link

Comment: Off topic query: You're a JEE aspirant, right?

Comment: @RiverX15  yes i am a jee aspirant

Comment: @AkshatJangra did you ever find the solution? If yes, could you maybe post it as an answer here, or as an edit to your post? I'm quite curious about how to solve it.

Comment: @GauravChandan i will try again tomorrow and will share the solution

Comment: @GauravChandan i have uploaded the answer

Comment: Thanks @AkshatJangra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PageA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAgXn.jpg)

For anyone who want the solution here it is.

[PageB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xOaT.jpg)